# groovy script not saving base 64 file

Tags: groovy

Below Groovy code is not storing the base 64 into the folder as expected:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def file_path = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("xml_file")
log.info("Output file: " + file_path)
file_path = file_path.replaceAll('.txt','_42PP.pdf')

def objFile = new java.io.File(file_path)
log.info("Output file: " + file_path)

def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder('publishAndReturnDocument#Response');
holder.declareNamespace('ns1','http://www.documentrequester.com/schemas/');
def byteArray = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:publishAndReturnDocumentResponse/publishAndReturnDocumentReturn" )
def b64 = new Base64()
def textBytes = b64.decode(byteArray.getBytes())
FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(objFile);
fos.write( textBytes );
fos.flush();
fos.close();

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("myFileStuff", "");
log.info("Output file: " + file_path)
```

expecting the base64 return to be saved as a file

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Have you tried without all the XML manipulation? Take some input, and write it to a file encoded as base 64. All the weirdness (an attribute called xml_file that contains a .txt file that you rename to a pdf, etc) is just confusing things here. Also, groovy has base64 encoding built in so you shouldn't need to import the Apache one ... But both will be the same so that's not the issue